# Lisp, calculating mixed expressions

Tags: lisp

i'am currently trying lisp and i need to solve a Problem. I want to write a function that takes a list as input and returns the calculated number. The elements that are not numbers should be added at the end of the list. Its important that the caluclated number is in front. At the end of this post you can see some function calls with the output i'am looking for.

```
(Function '(+ 100 1 2 3 4 5 6));-> 121 

(Function  '(+ 1 2 A B 3 C));-> (+ 6 C B A) 

(Function  '(+ A B C D 0));-> (+ D C B A)

(Function  '(- 2 3 4 5 6));-> -19 

(Function  '(- 1 B));-> (- 1 B) 

(Function  '(- 6 2 A B 3 C));-> (- 1 C B A)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Lisp is a big tent. Are you using Common Lisp? Scheme? Racket? Some other language? Rather than asking for someone to solve the exercise for you, you need to show some work; ask about problems you encounter when solving the exercise. "_I don't know where to start, can someone write this function for me?_" is not a great question.

Comment: `(- 2 3 4 5 6)` is `-16` and not `-19`. `-` is  non associative so  `(- B 1)` would also become `(- 1 B)` according to your logic, but if `B` is a variable that eg represents `6` the original expression is `5` while the resulting one becomes `-5`. Also Lisp is a familiy of languages, but as long as you don't edit the post and add some examples of what you have tried it is not likely people will post code in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

In any Lisp you have `car` to fetch the first element of a list and `cdr` for fetch the list without the first element and `cons` to add a list to the beginning of another list.

1. identify the operation by looking at the first element. Since `-` in a quoted list is a symbol you cannot apply this so you need to have a list of acceptable operations.
2. Loop through the rest of the list accumulating the non numbers to a list and the numbers using the operation.
3. `cons` the resulting number onto the list of symbols, then the operation making it `(op num . symbols)`

I'm assuming that `+` and `-` don't work as math as swithcing the order when using `-` or any other non associative operation changes the result.